# Elastic search ---: MUST_NOT query not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query in which i want to add a must_not clause that would discard all records that have blank data for a some field. I tried a lot of ways but none worked. when I issue the same query (mentioned below) with other specific fields then it works fine.

this query should get all records that do not have "registrationType1" field empty/blank

```
query:
{
"size": 20,
"_source": [
"registrationType1"
],
"query": {
"bool": {
"must_not": [
{
"term": {
"registrationType1": ""
}
}
]
}
}
}
```

the results below still contains "registrationType1" with empty values

```
results:

**"_source": {
"registrationType1": ""}}
, * {
"_index": "oh_animal",
"_type": "animals",
"_id": "3842002",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"registrationType1": "A&R"}}
, * {
"_index": "oh_animal",
"_type": "animals",
"_id": "3842033",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"registrationType1": "AMHA"}}
, * {
"_index": "oh_animal",
"_type": "animals",
"_id": "3842213",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"registrationType1": "AMHA"}}
, * {
"_index": "oh_animal",
"_type": "animals",
"_id": "3842963",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"registrationType1": ""}}
, * {
"_index": "oh_animal",
"_type": "animals",
"_id": "3869063",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"registrationType1": ""}}**
```

PFB mappings for the field above

```
"registrationType1": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword"
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `keyword` subfield in order to do this:

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "_source": [
    "registrationType1"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "registrationType1.keyword": ""       <-- change this
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What you did is querying `registrationType1` not `registrationType1.keyword`

Comment: I actually tried both,  I forgot to mention it in the description above

Comment: I just recreated your example on my local ES and it worked with with query above querying `registrationType1.keyword`, not receiving any docs with `"registrationType1": ""`

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: Tested on 6 and 7, it doesn't really matter, as it works on both versions the same way.

Comment: Tried everything but nothing seems to work, there are many properties in this index like price, gender, photo with same mappings and when I use the same query with these fields then the query returns desired results, I still don't know why it's not working with other properties. @Shabbir

Comment: What do you get when running `GET oh_animal`? I'd like to see the real mapping that is stored in ES, not the one you think you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify any text value on the text fields, there is basically nothing to analyze and return the documents accordingly.

In similar way, if you remove `must_not` and replace it with `must`, it would show empty results.

What you can do is, looking at your mapping, query must_not on `keyword` field. Keyword fields won't be analysed and in that way your query would return the results as you expect.

### Query

```
POST myemptyindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "registrationType1.keyword": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already tried adding "keyword", but it didn't work , sorry i forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using elasticsearch version 7.2, 
I replicated your data and ingested in my elastic index,and tried querying with and without .keyword.

I am getting the desired result when using the ".keyword" in the field name.It is not returning the docs which have registrationType1="".

Note - The query does not works when not using the ".keyword"

I have added my sample code below, have a look if that helps.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index="test", ignore=400, body={
"mappings": {
    "_doc": {
        "properties": {
            "registrationType1": {
                "type": "text",
                "field": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
})

data = {
"registrationType1": ""
}

es.index(index="test",doc_type="_doc",body=data,id=1)
search = es.search(index="test", body={
"size": 20,
"_source": [
    "registrationType1"
],
"query": {
    "bool": {
    "must_not": [
        {
            "term": {
                "registrationType1.keyword": ""
            }
        }
    ]
    }
}
})

print(search)
```

Executing the above should not return any results as we are inserting empty for the field

Answer (score 0):

There was some issue with the mappings itself, I deleted the index and re-indexed it with new mappings and its working now.